# two same hats earned on different community count

Tags: support, feature-request, winter-bash-2014

I am crazy about these hats, that we are having some fun while answering a question. I have earned the Chameleon hat on two different communities. My total hat count is 12, but it shows as 11, whereas when I click Chameleon hat it shows two under the category `You earned this hat on`. Does the profile display the number of type of hat earned or the total count of hats. If profile displays the number of type of hat, then the count can be displayed somewhere.

Comment: What else would you expect from a chameleon?

Comment: We don't trust no foreign hats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your profile shows the count of *unique* hats you earned; so if you have 5 hats on Stack Overflow and you earned one of those hats also on Super User, then it will still show as 5 hats.